Can‘t get git-remote-http binary after compile git with --with-curl option
I need a version of Git that supports the remote-http functionality. Due to certain constraints, I am unable to use a package manager and can only compile from source.
My machine is running CentOS 6. I downloaded several source packages: OpenSSL_1_1_1g.zip, curl-7.71.1.tar.gz, and Git v2.39.3.tar.gz. I compiled everything from scratch, but the resulting Git still does not have the remote-http functionality. There is no git-remote-http binary in /usr/local/libexec/git-core/.
compile openssl:
mkdir /opt/openssl
./config --prefix=/opt/openssl --shared
make -j 8 && make install

compile curl
mkdir /opt/curl
./configure --prefix=/opt/curl --with-ssl=/opt/openssl
make -j 8 && make install

compile git
make configure
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-curl=/opt/curl
make install CFLAGS='-std=gnu99'

Expecting
/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-remote-http exist and “git remote-http” cmd running normal
I have looked into many related issues, but none of them solved my problem. Can someone help me take a look?

I ran make prefix=/usr/local all install in Git which failed due to absence of Curl. I rerun it with CURLDIR=/opt/curl make prefix=/usr/local all install and got a lot of undefined references in libcurl. Perhaps this version of Curl is incompatible with this version of Git and must be of a different version. make configure && ./configure && make all didn't help either — the same list of undefined references.
